# Postman - How set up one specific “value” for all pairs “key”=“value” in the body before sending Request

Tags: testing, scripting, postman

I’d like to ask if I can set up one specific “value” for all pairs “key”=“value” in the body before sending Request.
My request body:

```
{
    "shop_status": "GOLD",
    "city": "LA",
    "name": "Beard Shop",
    "offers": [
        {
            "created_at": "2020-04-15T15:14:03.548282Z",
            "offer_id": "oof010329182",
            "amount": "320"
        },
        {
            "created_at": "2020-04-02T15:14:03.548282Z",
            "offer_id": "oof010329183",
            "amount": "180"
        },
        {
            "created_at": "2020-04-01T15:14:03.548282Z",
            "offer_id": "oof010329184",
            "amount": "750"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to set up the one date for all “created_at” keys. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't know anything about Postman. Is it possible that you could save this body as a variable first, then iterate over it to set your consistent value and only then pass the variable to the request?

Comment: @Phedg1 I'm saving this body as a variable first (I'm getting it from response of GET request). I have not found a way to replace values of "created at" fields with the other data.

Answer (score 0):

Postman allows for the use of [variables](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables/). You should be able to use a variable here. [Here](https://blog.postman.com/using-variables-inside-postman-and-collection-runner/) is a blog post about using them in a json body.

Comment: I know about variables. I need in script that will search all pairs "key": "value" and will set up one value for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the environment.
2. Set the key-value for the variable you want in the environment.
3. Use the variable with double curly braces in body.

Comment: Thanks! But this simple solution doesn't work for me. I added more information in my comment below